# Array undefined error for my Angular 2 application

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I am facing the below issue where I am trying to save JSON data coming from my API into an array of my Model object. However, when I console.log the array it prints "undefined". I even tried to print a simple array and it still says "undefined". I am not sure if I am missing anything here. My code is given below. Can some one please help as I am new to Angular 2 and TypeScript.

```
results : Array<Recipes> = new Array(20);
  sample = ['one','two','three'];

  getResults(): Observable<Recipes[]>{

    return this.http.get('<my API here which works perfectly.>')
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleErrorObservable);
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();

    console.log(this.sample); **---> This prints undefined in console**

    console.log(body);
    console.log(body.pagination.count);

    let total_no_of_results = body.pagination.count;
    let no_of_results;

    for(no_of_results = 0; no_of_results < total_no_of_results; no_of_results++) {
      //this.results[no_of_results] = new Recipes();
      this.results[no_of_results] = body.data[no_of_results].embed_url; **---> This gives "Cannot set property '0' of undefined" error and program exits**
    //this.results.push(image);
    }
    console.log(this.results);
    return this.results;
  }

  private handleErrorObservable (error: Response | any) {
    console.error(error.message || error);
    return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use this inside `extractData` you need

```
.map(this.extractData.bind(this))
```

or

```
.map((data) => this.extractData(data))
```

otherwise `this` won't point to the current class' instance.

Comment: Hi Gunter, I am able to retrieve the data from the "extractData". Problem is I am not able to save that data into an array because array says "undefined".

Comment: @venky4t Listen to Gunter, because he is right. Unless you bind `this.extractData`, it will be `unbound` function and will not have access to class fields. `this.extractData` is just a function, not a class method, so it cannot use `this.results` inside.

Comment: Excellent. That worked. Thank you Gunter and Lukasz.